# Passport Get Refresh Token OAuth

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

How to get refresh token in OAuth strategy using Passport? I am able to get accesss token but need to get refresh token as well.

From Google Documentation, found that we need to add ***access_type=offline*** in request.
How to achieve it using passport.

```
//STRATEGY
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: googleKeys.clientID,
      clientSecret: googleKeys.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: urls.cb,
    },
    (accessToken: any, refreshToken: any, profile: any, cb: any) => {

      //refreshToken is undefined
      cb(null, { email: profile._json.email });

    }
  )
);

router.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    ],
  })
);

//REDIRECT URI
router.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/", session: false }),
  (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send("Success");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the access type as an argument when using `passport.authenticate`.

```js
router.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    ],
    accessType: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent',
  })
);
```

Reference: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/issues/4#issuecomment-344460414

Comment: Giving error in typescript, but worked if typescript ignored.